# MariaDB - SQL Injection on insert

Tags: mariadb, sql-injection

There is a table name `queries` in my dummy database which has `name`, `email`, `phone`, `message`, and `region`. And there is a contact form in the UI which directly inserts the data into the queries table without validating or sanitizing anything. So I was performing some SQL injection on the form by adding `a','b','c','d','e'); DELETE FROM users; --` to one of the fields but it is not successful and getting the below error:-

**Error:-**

```
Error: INSERT INTO queries (name,email,phone,message,region) VALUES('a','b','c','d','e'); DELETE FROM users; --','sdas','1234567890','fsfdsf','home')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM users; --','sdas','1234567890','fsfdsf','home')' at line 1
```

**UI - Contact form**
[image]

The SQL query in the error message seems okay to me and I couldn't understand why it is giving the syntax error. Maybe because the query is followed by a comment?

Could someone please have a look and help me if I am missing anything?

Thank you.

Comment: Use parameters and then you won't have injection problems. You don't need to sanitize or validate anything, just separate code and data.

Comment: @Charlieface, i am doing it intensionally to understand how it can be exploited (just for learning purposes).

Comment: SQL is not the problem.  Show us the application code that is executing the SQL.

Comment: @RickJames, the application code is written in PHP and it is a simple insert with `$conn->query($sql)`. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @ArpitJain - Do you escape parameters typed in by users?  Or using "binding" to avoid "SQL Injection"?

Comment: @RickJames, No code is not using the parameterized query and this is intentional as I'm doing it just for learning purposes like what are the different ways of SQL injection and how they can be used by attackers to exploit the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to run two commands in the same PHP $conn->query().  That permits only one SQL statement at a time.

Comment: +1 Is there any other way you think the insert statement can be exploited with a single SQL statement?